# Don't understand Python lambda function syntax

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I don't understand how this syntax work and can't find documentation on it:

```
word = '123xyz567'
s = ''.join (c if c.isdigit() else ' 'for c in word)
```

Line 2 of code will take xyz123 and join together `"123 567"` into one string by passing in a lambda function to join

However, I am confused as to how this syntax works, normally a python if-else statement goes:

```
def example():
    for c in word:
        if c.isdigit():
            return c
        else:
            return ' '
```

Can someone either explain or direct me to documentation that explains to me the syntax structure of the lambda function passed into `.join()` and how I can use it properly?

Comment: Nothing there is a lambda function.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Teach me this language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things goining on here, none of them are `lambda`.

The first thing is a generetor expresion, which is of the form: `(<expresion> for <var> in <iterable>)`.
In your example `<expresion>` is `c if c.isdigit() else ' '`, `<var>` is `c`, and `iterable` is `word`.
It creates a generator (which is a sort of iterable) to pass to `str.join`.

The second thing is a ternary operator, which is of the form: `<expresion> if <bool-expresion> else <expresion>`.
In your example the first `<expresion>` is `c`, `<bool-expresion>` is `c.isdigit()`, and the second `<expresion>` is `' '`.
It returns the first `<expresion>` if the `<bool-expresion>` evaluates to `True`, else it returns the second `<expresion>`.

Everything put together, `(c if c.isdigit() else ' 'for c in word)` is a generator with all the characters of `word` but with non-digit characters replaced with a single space (each).

Answer (score 5):

That's not a lambda but a generator expression.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Almost like a list comprehension but instead a generator literal.

```
list = [a for a in [1,2,3]]
generator = (a for a in [1,2,3])
print(list) # [1,2,3]
print(generator) # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8ee3abd6d0>
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it might override the built-ins.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you displayed is not a `lambda` function, but rather a generator expression. See: [Generator expressions vs. list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/13552470)

You can read more on `lambda` here: [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

The `def` function you displayed wouldn't work properly with the `return` statement; use `yield` so that the function won't jump out at the first character:

```
def example(word):
    for c in word:
        if c.isdigit():
            yield c
        else:
            yield ' '
```

More on `yield` here: [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)